# count unique entries that have 2 where conditions - bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

i have a table like so:

```
email     | segment               | exit
---------------------------------------------
1@aol.com | abandoned_cart        | true
1@aol.com | purchased_last_7_days | false
2@aol.com | abandoned_cart        | true
2@aol.com | purchased_last_7_days | false
3@aol.com | abandoned_cart        | true
```

I am trying write a query to get a count of unique email addresses that have BOTH `abandoned_cart` = `true` and `purchase_last_7_days` = `false`

This is what I tried but recieved 0:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT email)
FROM `table_seg_changes` 
WHERE (segment_slug = 'purchased_last_7_days' AND exit = false) AND (segment_slug = 'abandoned_cart' AND exit = true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT email
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY email 
HAVING COUNTIF(
    (segment = 'abandoned_cart' AND exit) OR 
    (segment = 'purchased_last_7_days' AND NOT exit)
  ) = 2
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '1@aol.com' email, 'abandoned_cart' segment, TRUE exit UNION ALL
  SELECT '1@aol.com', 'purchased_last_7_days', FALSE UNION ALL
  SELECT '2@aol.com', 'abandoned_cart', TRUE UNION ALL
  SELECT '2@aol.com', 'purchased_last_7_days', FALSE UNION ALL
  SELECT '3@aol.com', 'abandoned_cart', TRUE
)
SELECT email
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY email 
HAVING COUNTIF(
    (segment = 'abandoned_cart' AND exit) OR 
    (segment = 'purchased_last_7_days' AND NOT exit)
  ) = 2
```

with result

```
Row email    
1   1@aol.com    
2   2@aol.com
```

Note: above assumes there is no duplicate entries for segments/exit values for the same email (as it is looks like from your example)